# How to estimate the copy time of a table in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table of 200 Terabyte and I want to make a copy of it.

How could I calculate the time it would take, before I actually do it?

Extra:

1)The table is partitioned by ingestion time of the data.

2)I would copy it under the same dataset.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try copying it?

Comment: Not yet, will update with the result when I do.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa it took roughly 18 minutes. The funny thing was that the percentage of the job completion was 0% for the 10 minutes and then when I checked again at completion it was 100%. So it wasn't very accurate in calculating the estimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An actual estimate is hard without doing a performance test. However we can estimate an upper bound: lets imagine the this is bottlenecked on a single network 10gbps network link. Then we would expect this to take 200*1024*8/10/3600=45.5 hours.

As I imagine BigQuery is much more parallel than that, I'd expect 45 hours as the *longest* the transfer could take.